# Linux running games in another x-session

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, performance, x-windows, wine, xephyr

I have been trying to optimize my settings to the maximum lately and someone told me that running a game in another xsessions w/ another user would increase my perfs.

It will also allow me to kill it from the other x session at anytime without having to restart the computer when it gets stuck.

Today I have tried to do that in a Xephyr "screen" and I had ten times less fps on glxgears, I haven't tried on a real game ran by wine yet.

Just looking for some advices on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51486&highlight=xinit:+Connection+refused+(errno+111)

Comment: That post was from 2005 so I was about to comment that this is almost certainly outdated and no longer relevant. But then I noticed that this answer was accepted, so presumably the OP tried it out and it did resolve the problems. Surprising, and good post, finding that from nearly 5 years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

This one sounds a little odd to me, since you need another session + another complete desktop environment for the new user, which just has to grind on the performance. At least that's my opinion.

Additionally to it, normally the kernel does not freeze if x is crashing...the lowlevel shortcuts (like Alt + Druck + K for restarting X) should always work.

Comment: Yeah that's the reason why I'm asking. But apparently It's good you can remove all effects / compiz things + reduce settings to the minimum on the "new xsession". Just looking for more info about it

Comment: @mml you might want to try out xgame with does exactly that http://xgame.tlhiv.com/